# dojo enhanced datagrid loses focus after edit

Tags: datagrid, dojo, edit

I have an enhanced `datagrid` that uses a `jsonreststore`.

I have set the editable cell to auto-save. To do this, I added a onApplyCellEdit property. after successful save (by pressing enter key) the server responds with the new data and my `datagrid` is updated. however, the focus on the cell just edited loses focus. As a result I cannot use the arrow key to navigate to the next cell, forcing me to use the mouse. Is there any way to regain focus so that I can use the keyboard to navigate after editing?
I have done following code to kind of regain the focus using `setTimeout` but I think it is not a good solution because if it takes too long for the server to respond the cell will regain focus first and when the response comes in and cell is updated, the cell will lose focus:

```
 var accounts = new EnhancedGrid({
     structure: account_layout,
     selectionMode: "single",
     canSort: function(){
         return false
     },
     onApplyCellEdit: function(inValue,inRowIndex,inFieldIndex){
         if(this.store){
             this.store.save();
             window.setTimeout(function(){
                 var cells = accounts.layout.cells;
                 var fieldLocation;

                 for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
                     if(inFieldIndex === cells[i].field){
                         fieldLocation = i;
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 accounts.focus.setFocusCell(cells[fieldLocation],inRowIndex);
             },500);
         }
     }
 });
```

I also tried:

```
this.store.save().then(function(){ ...});
```

But it's not working.

**EDIT**
To clarify question, I added sentence after first sentence of 2nd paragraph.

Comment: What version of dojo are you using?

Also, if the server is already responding with the new data, why would you need to call this.store.save() again?

Comment: I'm using version 1.7. The `this.store.save()` triggers the save request to the server(I'm trying to implement an autosave). Anyway, I added an `onComplete()` callback inside `save()` method and that seemed to do what I want. I still needed to add the setTimeout though.